# PowerShell: Why can't Start-Process take both -Verb and -RSO?

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, wmi, start-process

Newbie to PowerShell here. I'm trying to run `Start-Process` with elevated privilege (via `-Verb RunAs`) and log the results (via `-RSO output.txt`). For some reason, it won't accept both. This works fine, for example:

```
Start-Process cmd -Verb RunAs
```

and this:

```
Start-Process cmd -RedirectStandardOutput output.txt
```

but not this:

```
PS C:\> saps cmd -Verb RunAs -RSO output.txt
Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ saps cmd -Verb RunAs -RSO output.txt
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Running `Start-Process -?` seems to verify my suspicions. Note how `-RedirectStandardOutput` and `-Verb` are listed in different sections:

```
SYNTAX
    Start-Process [-FilePath] <string> [[-ArgumentList] <string[]>] [-Credential <pscredential>] [-WorkingDirectory
    <string>] [-LoadUserProfile] [-NoNewWindow] [-PassThru] [-RedirectStandardError <string>] [-RedirectStandardInpu
    <string>] **[-RedirectStandardOutput <string>]** [-WindowStyle <ProcessWindowStyle> {Normal | Hidden | Minimized |
    Maximized}] [-Wait] [-UseNewEnvironment]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Start-Process [-FilePath] <string> [[-ArgumentList] <string[]>] [-WorkingDirectory <string>] [-PassThru] **[-Verb
    <string>]** [-WindowStyle <ProcessWindowStyle> {Normal | Hidden | Minimized | Maximized}] [-Wait]
    [<CommonParameters>]
```

Why are they mutually exclusive, and what can I do to bypass this?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not aware, off hand, of the reason that this is the case. However I would be curious to know why you want this? In case we are looking at and XY problem

Comment: @Matt I mentioned why in the second sentence of my question.

Comment: The underlying mechanism Windows provides for elevating a process doesn't allow for output redirection.  You'll need to do it in two steps: launch an elevated process (perhaps a Powershell command line) that then launches your target process with output redirection.